# Difference ways to initialize char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization

What is the difference between initializing a `char` array with a string in curly braces and without curly braces?

```
char arr[] = {"string"};
```

or

```
char arr[] = "string";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. This is directly addressed by C99, *6.7.8 Initialization*:

> 14. An array of character type may be initialized by **a character string literal, optionally
>       enclosed in braces**. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the
>       terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>       elements of the array.

(Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 0):

Although Melpomene's quote of the standard is the only definitive answer, the following may be enlightning:

To initialize an array, one writes the elements of the initialization between curly braces, separated by commas, for example:

```
int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

To initialize an array of characters, one can write likewise:

```
char array[]= = {'s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'};
```

but for convenience the standard allows that to be:

```
char array[] = "string";
```

and to be compitible with the forms shown earlier, the standard also allows:

```
char array[] = { "string" };
```

Comment: More enlightning: an array of strings which use less space: `char * array[] = {"string1", "longerstring", "short"}`. This is different to `char array[3][20]`.

Comment: Well, the standard also allows `int i = { 0 };` and `char c = { 'X' };` ("*The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces.*"). It's probably for compatibility with that.